# Wordpress add different menu group in home page and inner page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu

I want to display different menus on home page and inner page,
My site home page link is: http://www.cognitiveasia.com/
and inner site link like : http://www.cognitiveasia.com/brand-advocacy/what-is-lorem-ipsum/

How i can manage by custom codding or plugin?

Answer (score 1):

first, in your functions.php define 2 menu positions:

```
function my_menus() {
    register_nav_menu('home-menu-location','Home Location');
    register_nav_menu('inner-menu-location','Inner Page Location');

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_menus' );
```

then, in your header.php use:

```
<nav>
<?php 
if (is_home()) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'home-menu-location' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'inner-menu-location' ) );
}
?>
</nav>
```

after this, you will have two menu positions in wordpress backend and you can add a diferent menu for each position

Comment: I have already tried to implement this solutions, but i'm using `dt-the7` theme... i have found `header.php` file but not getting any header related changes... any Idea?